# Hotkey to Frame all Objects into viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, customization, selection-tools

Is it possible to set hotkey <kbd>F</kbd> to View/Frame All objects into all viewports, and if any objects are selected will frame that object within all view ports as well with key <kbd>F</kbd>.

I would be very grateful for any tips.

Answer (score 2):

To frame all objects in one viewport do: <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> Both with the origin as the camera focal point

Or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>
This will also bring the 3D cursor back to the origin.

Numpad <kbd>.</kbd> will frame the currently selected object or objects.

Numpad <kbd>/</kbd> will frame the currently selected object or objects and hide everything else, until you press it again.

You can change them here (to <kbd>F</kbd>):
[image]

This however will affect only the (single) viewport under the mouse cursor.
I imagine affecting multiple viewport at once will require a script, but i'm not sure.

**EDIT:**

If you want to experiment with a different hotkey layout you can always click Add Key-config Preset (the little "+" icon), to make a new preset and try some things without messing up you current key setup.

[image]

Comment: thx fjoer, very helpful and so close... is it possible a hotkey can frame all unselected objects and any selected object? would be very grateful for solution here.

Comment: I updated my answer a bit. Hope that helps. I understand my answer isn't the perfect solution you're looking for. But also not sure I understand you question in your comment. You can frame all unselected objects in one viewport and frame any selected objects in another. Though i guess this is an example of the UI behavior you kinda didn't want. : )

Comment: of thanks for the suggestion. to make it easier; in the perps view only is there any solution to frame all unselected elements with F hotkey, and if i then select a object how can i get the F hotkey to frame that selected object? if not possible in blender could this be done with shift key?

Comment: I don't think you can. If you replace both "Numpad ." and "Home" keys with "F", only the one you assigned first will work. (It seems like there is no need for them to interfere with each other but apparently they do) You can of course replace "Home" with "F" to frame all you objects, and replace "Numpad ." with "Shift F" for framing one or more selected objects. Then you can do one framing action after another.

Comment: yes thx so much. but is there a way to hotkey frame selected (on the .> key). for your refer frame select is linked to (. Del)

Comment: We might not have the same hotkey setup, but i suggest you just try it, and see if it works. I edited my answer accordingly. But I think if these settings don't work for you, you'll have to ask a question how to change key behavior via script. In any case, I don't have much more info on this so I hope it helps : )